# Register and Reset form always available

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.5

today I have noticed I can always access the register and reset form regardless if I am authenticated or not.

Here is my security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:
                delete_cookies:
                    activeGame: {}
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Regarding http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html#forcing-the-user-to-re-authenticate-before-accessing-certain-resources it seems "normal" to be able to access this pages.

But how can I "easily" disable it for **authenticated user** or did I miss anything?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to accomplish what you are looking for by using the newly introduced allow_if expression for access controls.

```
- { path: ^/register, allow_if: "not is_authenticated()" }
```

Another way may be:

```
- { path: ^/register, allow_if: "user == 'anon'" }
```

I havent fully tested this but it should only allow users who are not authenticated fully or authenticated remembered to access that path

Here is a little bit about the [security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)

[Here are some of the variable and functions available in expressions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-expression-variables)

Then here is some info on the [Expressions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html) you can use in `allow_if`

IF however, you do not want to throw a 403 Access Denied Exception when logged in users try and access those pages. Instead you would like to redirect them elsewhere then you can add a check to their respective controller actions. Something like:

```
public function registerAction()
{
    if (true === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('some_route_to_send_them_to'));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't be clear enough in my question. I want to disable the forms for authenticated users.

Comment: Aw, so you want to restrict those urls to only users who are not logged in? Wouldnt you still want a logged in user to be able to reset their password? Ill get back to you shortly if i find a way

Comment: Interesting point, didn't consider it yet. I thought you can do it via profile edit or in other words I will implement it like that. But in general register shouldn't be available for authenticated users. Yes to your first question.

Comment: Check my updated answer and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hum ... I did read the whole stuff but I wasn't aware of that usage. :) First way tested and works for me.

Comment: One additional note you can add, you have to create another rule for register/confirmed. I used `path: ^/register/confirmed$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` otherwise the user can't get the successful confirmed message or you change the routing.

Comment: the path `^/register` should match both `/register` and `/register/confirmed`. You should not need to add another access_control for it. Unless when reaching `/register/confirmed` the user has been logged in then you would need to add a rule for it.

Comment: You need the exception of `/register/confirmed`, because you will redirected on this page after confirming your account and then you are logged in. The user gets there a message "Congrats %username%, your account is now activated." otherwise you will get there a 403.

Comment: In that case you would want to use `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`. To check that a user is logged in, to access that page. Logged in users do also pass the check for `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` which is why that works but is misleading when read by another developer.